# How do I extract firebase functions to an object in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm new to object oriented programming and am trying to move logic out of my view controller and into its own model so I can reuse endpoint calls and such, but I can't figure out how to alert my view controller that the result has occurred from within the object. Within javascript, I'd normally just set the function to return a value but it is not allowing me to return anything other than Void `Cannot convert return expression of type 'Void' to return type 'String'`.

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class CloudFunctions {

    let functions = Functions.functions()

    func addNewAccount(param1: String) -> String {
        functions.httpsCallable(FunctionsConstants.myFunction).call(["param1Name":param1]) { (result, error) in
            if let e = error {
                return "\(e)"
            } else {
                if let result = result {
                    return "\(result.data)"
                } else {
                    return "Sorry, we couldn't unwrap the result."
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and in my view controller I'm calling it like

```
let cloudFunctions = CloudFunctions()
self.result = cloudFunctions.addNewAccount(param1: dataHere)
```

I thought I might be able to create a didSet on result to update the UI, but it won't let the function go through because I get the error: `Cannot convert return expression of type 'Void' to return type 'String'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a completion

```
func addNewAccount(param1: String,completion:@escaping(String -> ())){
    functions.httpsCallable(FunctionsConstants.myFunction).call(["param1Name":param1]) { (result, error) in
        if let e = error {
            return "\(e)"
        } else {
            if let result = result {
                completion("\(result.data)")
            } else {
                 completion("Sorry, we couldn't unwrap the result.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
addNewAccount(param1:"") { str in

}
```

Comment: This worked! Totally new syntax to me that I haven't seen before. Is this the common way to handle this type of function?